# Looking for Excel formula that return the value of the first cell in a row for last non-empty cell in different row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have spreadsheet like this one:

```
a b c d e f 
1     1
1 1   1 1  
1 1 1
```

I'm looking for a formula that will return d, e and c:

```
 formula   a b c d e f 
    d      1     1
    e      1 1   1 1  
    c      1 1 1
```

I have tried something like this

> =INDEX($O$1:$XFD$1;1;MATCH(VLOOKUP(2;1/(O2:XFD2<>"");O2:XFD2);O2:XFD2;0))

but it doesn't work whatsoever.

[EDIT for Rajesh S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT8ed.gif)

As you can see I found the solution

> =INDEX($A$1$:$XFD$1;1;LOOKUP(2;1/(O2:XFD2<>"");COLUMN(O2:XFD2)))

Comment: I use VBA user-defined function when I need to solve such task. The code will be simple enough.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share proper Screen Shot containing Col Name &  Row Number,,, Check C hasn't last empty cell bank!!

Comment: I got it, it's `=INDEX($A$1$:$XFD$1;1;LOOKUP(2;1/(O2:XFD2<>"");COLUMN(O2:XFD2)))`